# Could not resolve Kotlin Gradle plugin after upgrade

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I've upgraded Gradle version from `7.0.2` to `7.2.2` and Kotlin Gradle plugin from `1.4.21` to `1.7.0` and  Android Studio builds my project without any errors, but every time I try to build the project using terminal it causes these errors:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'project-agp-upgrade'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externall
y. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0:
          - gradle70JavadocElements
          - gradle70RuntimeElements
          - gradle70SourcesElements
          - javadocElements
          - runtimeElements
          - sourcesElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its depe
ndencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible wi
th Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its depe
ndencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies
 declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 
8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies
 declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a 
jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
          - Variant 'gradle70ApiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packag
ed as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21.
     Required by:
         project : > androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externall
y. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0:
          - gradle70JavadocElements
          - gradle70RuntimeElements
          - gradle70SourcesElements
          - javadocElements
          - runtimeElements
          - sourcesElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its depe
ndencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible wi
th Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its depe
ndencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies
 declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 
8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies
 declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
```

I've searched a lot on this problem, but couldn't figure out what I should do to make it work.

My project has multiple modules, two main build.gradle files are:

Project build.gradle:

```
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.DetektCreateBaselineTask


buildscript {

    ext {
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        compileSdkVersion = 33
        minSdkVersion = 21
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        kotlinVersion = '1.7.20'
        coroutinesVersion = "1.6.4"
        ktxVersion = '1.9.0'
        googleServicesVersion = '4.3.10'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$googleServicesVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt").version("1.19.0")
}

dependencies {
    detekt project(':detekt-rules')

    detektPlugins "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:1.19.0"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

// some Detekt plugin tasks

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.android"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.versionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            testCoverageEnabled = false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled false
        }

        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            multiDexEnabled true

            // Uncomment to reduce apk size
            //ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"

dependencies {
    implementation project(":module1")
    implementation project(":module2") // and other modules etc.

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.44.2"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.44.2"
    compileOnly "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0"
    compileOnly "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"

    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.10"

    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.1" 
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.22"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.1"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1"
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.13.3"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1"

    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:4.9.3"

    implementation "com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2"
}
```

It seems to me that the problem can be because of navigation-safe-args plugin, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After MANY hours of thinking how to fix this problem, I've decided to reinstall Gradle, so

1. I deleted Gradle related files in `С:\` and `*user name*\.gradle` directories;
2. Downloaded the needed version from official Gradle website and installed it;
3. I also modified `path` system environmental variable and reinstalled JDK 11.

After doing all of it eventually my project started building from Android Studio interface and terminal. I hope it'll help someone not to struggle like I did

Answer (score -1):

You can check the java version in the project structure. It should be set to version 11.
Let me know if you face any error after that.

Comment: I've changed java version from 1.8 to 11 and errors are still here :(

Comment: Please invalidate and restart your android studio and sync gradle..  also i can see navigation library has lower version of kotlin. Can you post the error again after doing all this and send the screenshot of the java version also.